# Is $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3}$ uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Last week I had an assignment to show $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3}$ for $x\ge0$ does not converge uniformly, but I misread the question as "show $f(x)$ is not uniformly continuous."

The actual problem went on to show that $f(x)$ is continuous, but I have been stumped by the question I misread:

> Is $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3}$ uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$?

I asked my professor about the problem today, but unfortunately we still didn't come up with an answer (and while my professor believes that $f(x)$ is not uniformly continuous, I suspect that it is).

__

Things I have proven about $f(x)$ that I can explain or one can assume in an answer: The series does not converge uniformly to $f(x)$, $f(x)$ is continuous, and $f(x)>\frac{x-1}{2}$.

Comment: From some numerical examples, it appears that $f$ is differentiable and $f'$ is bounded. Hence $f$ is uniformly continuous: $|f(x) - f(y)| = \left| f'(\xi_{x,y}) \right| \left| x - y \right|$ by the mean value theorem, and hence $\left| f(x) - f(y) \right| \leq \left| \sup_{\xi \in \mathbb R} f'(\xi) \right| \left| x - y \right|$.

Comment: I don't want to do all the work of posting an answer, but one has $$\int_x^\infty \frac{ux^2}{u^3+x^3}\,du = \frac{\log 8 + \pi\sqrt3}9 x,$$ which certainly suggests that you're right and the function is uniformly continuous. (The maximum of $f_n(x) = nx^2/(n^3+x^3)$ occurs at $x=n\root3\of 2$, so we're past that and the integral test applies.)

Comment: @TedShifrin: I agree. +1 But how would you argue for the uniform continuity just from the convergence of the series to or bounds with the integral and without looking at, say, the derivative with respect to $x$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the derivative of $f$ is indeed bounded on $[0,\infty),$ which implies $f$ is uniformly continuous there. I'll give an outline: Let's write

$$f(x) = x^2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^3 + x^3}.$$

This will give

$$\tag 1 f'(x) = 2x \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^3 + x^3} + x^2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-3x^2n}{(n^3 + x^3)^2}.$$

(You verify this on any bounded interval, where all convergence in sight is uniform. Since differentiation is a local property, we get $(1)$.)

Now the right side of $(1)$ will be bounded if we show

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{n^3 + x^3} = O(1/x) \,\,\text {   and    } \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(n^3 + x^3)^2} = O(1/x^4)$$

as $x\to \infty.$ OK, I'll leave it here for now. Some things to check.

Comment: How do you know you can take derivatives under the summation?

Comment: Let $g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^3 + x^3}.$ That series converges uniformly on $[0,\infty),$ so $g$ is well defined and continuous there. The series of derivatives converges uniformly on any $[0,a].$ Thus we have $g'(x)$ existing and equal to the sum of derivatives on any $[0,a].$ Therefore $g$ is differentiable on $[0,\infty),$ with $g'(x)$ equal to the sum of derivatives there. Since $f(x) = x^2g(x),$ we just use the product rule and the above to answer your question.

Comment: That's right. The sums $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{nx}{n^3+x^3}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{nx^4}{(n^3+x^3)^2}$ are, indeed, bounded. Proof: split the summation from $0$ to $[x]-1$ and the tail. The former can be written as a Riemann sum and, thus, converges to the corresponding integral when $x\to +\infty$, the latter can be estimated by an integral that has a value that does not depend on $x$.

Comment: The uniform boundedness of those series has now been discussed here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3235330/42969.