# Show $ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx}{n^3 + x^3}$ ,$\ g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^4n}{(n^3 + x^3)^2}$ are bounded on $[0, \infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $f(x), g(x)$ are defined as following on $[0 , \infty)$,
$$\tag 1 f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx}{n^3 + x^3}$$

$$\tag 2 g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^4n}{(n^3 + x^3)^2}.$$
. Then how to show that $f,g$ are bounded function on $[0 , \infty)$?

I found this problem on this 
[Is $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3}$ uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844169/is-fx-sum-n-1-infty-fracnx2n3x3-uniformly-continuous-on-0-inf).

In solution's last steps, i don't know why this is correct answer.

Could you explain for me to elaborate?

Thank you.

Comment: $O(\frac{1}{x})$ means it is bounded when $x$ goes to infinity, i.e., $O(\frac{1}{x})\le K\frac{1}{x}$ when $x\to\infty$ for some $K>0$.

Comment: In fact, The main purpose of this question is why f,g are bounded function. So, notion of ' $O(\frac{1}{x}) $' is not proper answer to me , but thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First note that for $x \ge 0$ and $n \in \Bbb N$
$$
 \frac{x^4n}{(n^3 + x^3)^2} =\frac{x^3}{n^3+x^3}\cdot\frac{nx}{n^3 + x^3}
< \frac{nx}{n^3 + x^3}
$$
and therefore $g(x) \le f(x)$, so that it suffices to show that the function $f$ is bounded on $[0, \infty)$.

---

For $0 \le x \le 1$ we have
$$
 \frac{nx}{n^3 + x^3} \le \frac{1}{n^2} \implies f(x) \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}  . 
$$

For fixed $x >1$ and $m =1, 2, 3, \ldots$ consider all $n$ with $x(m-1) \le n < xm$. For each of these $n$,
$$
\frac{nx}{n^3 + x^3} \le \frac{mx^2}{(m-1)^3x^3 + x^3} = \frac 1x \cdot \frac{m}{(m-1)^3+1}
$$
and there are at most $\lfloor x \rfloor +1$ of such $n$. Therefore
$$
 f(x) \le \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor +1}{x} \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{m}{(m-1)^3+1} \le 2 \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{m}{(m-1)^3+1} 
$$
for $x > 1$.

---

*Previous solution (more complicated)*: The idea for estimating $f(x)$ is to replace the infinite sum by a “similar” integral:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nx}{n^3+x^3} \lessapprox \int_0^\infty \frac{ux}{u^3+x^3} \, dx  = \int_0^\infty \frac{v}{v^3+1} \, .
$$
The two integrals are equal via the substitution $u=xv$, and the last integral is independent of $x$, so that we get a uniform upper bound. Of course the “approximate inequality” must be stated and proved precisely, so here are the gory details:

For fixed $x>0$ we consider the function $\varphi$ defined on $[0, \infty)$ by
$$
\varphi(t) = \frac{tx}{t^3 + x^3} \,.
$$
It is easy to see (by calculating the derivative) that $\varphi $ is increasing on  $[0, \frac{x}{2^{1/3}}]$ and decreasing on $[\frac{x}{2^{1/3}}, \infty)$.

If $\frac{x}{2^{1/3}} \le 1$ then $\varphi$ is decreasing on $[1, \infty)$, so that each term in the sum of $f(x)$ (with the exception of the first term) can be estimate above by an integral over $\varphi$:
$$
 f(x) = \varphi(1) + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \varphi(n) \\
 \le \varphi(1) + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \int_{n-1}^n \varphi(u) \, du
 = \varphi(1) + \int_1^\infty \varphi(t) \, dt
 \le 1 + \int_0^\infty \frac{ux}{u^3+x^3} \, du \, 
$$
and with the substitution $u = xv$ we get 
$$ \tag{*}
f(x) \le 1 + \int_1^\infty \frac{v}{v^3+1} \, dv \, .
$$

If $\frac{x}{2^{1/3}} > 1$ then we can proceed similarly. With $m = \lfloor \frac{x}{2^{1/3}} \rfloor$ we  estimate
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{m-1} \varphi(n) + \varphi(m) + \varphi(m+1) + \sum_{n=m+2}^{\infty} \varphi(n) \\
\le \int_0^\frac{x}{2^{1/3}} \varphi(u) \, du + 2 \varphi(\frac{x}{2^{1/3}}) +  \int_\frac{x}{2^{1/3}}^\infty \varphi(u) \, du \\
= \frac{4}{ 2^{1/3} \cdot 3x} + \int_0^\infty \frac{ux}{u^3+x^3} \, du \\
< 1 + \int_0^\infty \frac{ux}{u^3+x^3} \, du = 1 + \int_0^\infty \frac{v}{v^3+1} \, dv 
$$
so that $(*)$ holds as well.

Comment: Really really good answer.. Thank you.

Comment: @hew: I have added another (simpler) solution.

Comment: Wow!! I really want to thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A simple proof:

Clearly:
$$
n^3+x^3\ge \frac{1}{4}(n+x)^3 \tag{1}
$$
and hence
$$
0\le \frac{nx}{n^3+x^3} \le \frac{4nx}{(n+x)^3}\le\frac{4(n+x)x}{(n+x)^3}=\frac{4x}{(n+x)^2}.
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nx}{n^3+x^3}\le 
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4x}{(n+x)^2}=\frac{4x}{(1+x)^2}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{4x}{(n+x)^2}\le \frac{4x}{(1+x)^2}+\int_1^\infty \frac{4x\,ds}{(s+x)^2} \tag{2}\\=
\frac{4x}{(1+x)^2}+\frac{4x}{(1+x)}.
$$

Meanwhile
$$
\frac{x^4n}{(x^3+n^3)^2}=\frac{nx}{n^3+x^3}\cdot\frac{x^3}{x^3+n^3}\le 
\frac{nx}{n^3+x^3}.
$$
**Notes.** Inequality $(1)$ holds since
$$
4(n^3+x^3)=4(n+x)(n^2-nx+x^2)=(n+x)(4n^2-4nx+4x^2)
=(n+x)(n^2+2nx+x^2+3n^2-6nx+3x^2)=(n+x)^3+3(n+x)(n-x)^2\ge(n+x)^3.
$$
The last inequality in $(2)$ holds since if $f: [1,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ is decreasing, then $\sum_{n=2}^\infty f(n)\le \int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx.$

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the third line and this argument doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, $\frac{4x}{(n+x)^2}\le \frac{4}{n^2}$ does not hold for fixed $x > 1$ and large $n$.

Comment: @martinR See my corrected answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what is commonly known as [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition), it basically means that asympotically the function behaves like $\frac{1}{x}$ for large x, in this concrete example its used to denote that $x \cdot \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{n^3 + x^3}$ converges to some finite number, therefore is bounded for all $x \in [0, \infty)$, same for the other series and $O\left(\frac{1}{x^4}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you!  May i ask you why $f(x)$ is bounded by some finite number?