# Analysis of convergence (pointwise, local uniform, uniform)

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

How can we check if some series for example
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3}\qquad x>0
$$
is convergent pointwise / locally uniformed / uniformed? What are the methods / tools to check the convergence of such series?

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange. You will have more luck getting useful answers if you provide some context. What have you tried? Where specifically are stuck? What tools are available to you?

Comment: Compare [Is $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3}$ uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844169/is-fx-sum-n-1-infty-fracnx2n3x3-uniformly-continuous-on-0-inf)

Comment: The problem is that I only know the definitions of this convergences types but don't know which tools use in analyzing such examples. It's just an example, I'm asking for some universal metods

Comment: @trapper Were you able to check at least pointwise convergence?

Comment: @PierreCarre I would try to compare the series with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3}$ which does converges

Comment: @trapper You should compare with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ instead... Don't miss the $n$ in the numerator.

Comment: @PierreCarre I don't know how to write the proof for this... How to formally compare these series?

Comment: You just use the fact that if $\lim \frac{a_n}{b_n}$ is finite and nonzero the series $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ have the same nature. In this case, for a fixed $x>0$, you can compute the limit 
$$\lim \dfrac{\frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3}}{\frac{1}{n^2}}= x^2$$
and take your conclusion.